# ¿Cómo corrijo el siguiente error? - Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in

Tags: php

Estoy teniendo problemas al querer "modificar usuario"(puntualmente)

```php
    /*----=========
    EDITAR USUARIO
    =========----*/
    static public function ctrEditarUsuario()
    {
        if (isset($_POST["editarUsuario"])) {
            if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $_POST["editarNombre"])) {
                /*----========
                VALIDAR IMAGEN
                ========----*/
                $ruta = $_POST["fotoActual"];
                if (isset($_FILES["editarFoto"]["tmp_name"])) {
                    list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize($_FILES["editarFoto"]["tmp_name"]);
                    $nuevoAncho = 500;
                    $nuevoAlto = 500;

                    /*----=============================================
                    CREAMOS EL DIRECTORIO DONDE VAMOS A GUARDAR LA FOTO
                    =============================================----*/
                    $directorio = "vistas/img/usuarios/" . $_POST["editarUsuario"];

                    /*----=======================================================
                    PRIMERO PREGUNTAMOS SI EXISTE OTRA IMAGEN EN LA BD
                    =======================================================----*/
                    if (!empty($_POST["fotoActual"])) {
                        unlink($_POST["fotoActual"]);
                    } else {
                        mkdir($directorio, 0755);
                    }

                    /*----=================================================================
                    DE ACUERDO AL TIPO DE IMAGEN APLICAMOS LAS FUNCIONES POR DEFECTO DE PHP
                    =================================================================----*/
                    if ($_FILES["editarFoto"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") {
                        /*----==============================
                        GUARDAMOS LA IMAGEN EN EL DIRECTORIO
                        ==============================----*/
                        $aleatorio = mt_rand(100, 999);
                        $ruta = "vistas/img/usuarios/" . $_POST["editarUsuario"] . "/" . $aleatorio . ".jpg";
                        $origen = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["editarFoto"]["tmp_name"]);
                        $destino = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto);
                        imagecopyresized($destino, $origen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto, $ancho, $alto);
                        imagejpeg($destino, $ruta);
                    }

                    /*----=================================================================
                    DE ACUERDO AL TIPO DE IMAGEN APLICAMOS LAS FUNCIONES POR DEFECTO DE PHP
                    =================================================================----*/
                    if ($_FILES["editarFoto"]["type"] == "image/png") {
                        /*----==============================
                        GUARDAMOS LA IMAGEN EN EL DIRECTORIO
                        ==============================----*/
                        $aleatorio = mt_rand(100, 999);
                        $ruta = "vistas/img/usuarios/" . $_POST["editarUsuario"] . "/" . $aleatorio . ".png";
                        $origen = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES["editarFoto"]["tmp_name"]);
                        $destino = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto);
                        imagecopyresized($destino, $origen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto, $ancho, $alto);
                        imagepng($destino, $ruta);
                    }
                }

                $tabla = "usuarios";
                if ($_POST["editarPassword"] != "") {
                    if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["editarPassword"])) {
                        $encriptar = crypt($_POST["editarPassword"], '$2a$07$asxx54ahjppf45sd87a5a4dDDGsystemdev$');
                    } else {
                        echo '<script>          
                      swal.fire({                     
                          type: "error",
                          title: "¡El ususario no puede ir vacío o llevar caracteres especiales!",
                          showConfirmButton: true,
                          confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
                          closeOnConfirm: false
                      }).then((result)=>{            
                          if(result.value){                  
                              window.location = "usuarios";                    
                          }
                      });     
                      </script>';
                    }
                } else {
                    $encriptar = "passwordActual";
                }

                $datos = array(
                    "nombre" => $_POST["editarNombre"],
                    "usuario" => $_POST["editarUsuario"],
                    "password" => $encriptar,
                    "perfil" => $_POST["editarPerfil"],
                    "foto" => $ruta
                );

                $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::mdlEditarUsuario($tabla, $datos);

                if ($respuesta == "ok") {
                    echo '<script>
                                  swal.fire({
                                      type: "success",
                                      title: "¡El usuario ha sido guardado correctamente!",
                                      showConfirmButton: true,
                                      confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
                                      closeOnConfirm: false                 
                                  }).then((result)=>{                     
                                      if(result.value){                      
                                          window.location = "usuarios";                          
                                      }
                                  });                        
                                  </script>';
                }
            } else {
                echo '<script>          
                        swal.fire({                     
                            type: "error",
                            title: "¡El nombre no puede ir vacío o llevar caracteres especiales!",
                            showConfirmButton: true,
                            confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
                            closeOnConfirm: false
                        }).then((result)=>{            
                            if(result.value){                  
                                window.location = "usuarios";                    
                            }
                        });     
                        </script>';
            }
        }
    }
```

contraseña y foto de perfil)..pero me está arrojando el siguiente error...

> Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\cautiva_hse\controladores\usuarios.controlador.php:150
> Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\cautiva_hse\controladores\usuarios.controlador.php(150):
> getimagesize('') #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\cautiva_hse\vistas\modulos\usuarios.php(248):
> ControladorUsuarios::ctrEditarUsuario() #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\cautiva_hse\vistas\plantilla.php(107):
> include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3
> C:\xampp\htdocs\cautiva_hse\controladores\plantilla.controlador.php(7):
> include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #4
> C:\xampp\htdocs\cautiva_hse\index.php(17):
> ControladorPlantilla::ctrPlantilla() #5 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\cautiva_hse\controladores\usuarios.controlador.php on
> line 150

Comment: cual es la linea 150 en usuarios.controlador.php???

Comment: list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize($_FILES["editarFoto"]["tmp_name"]);

Comment: puedes hacer var_dump($_FILES["editarFoto"]["tmp_name"]); antes de esa linea? y me dices que te sale...

Comment: string(0) "" Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\cautiva_hse\controladores\usuarios.controlador.php:151 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\cautiva_hse\controladores\usuarios.controlador.php(151): getimagesize('') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\cautiva_hse\vistas\modulos\usuarios.php(248): ControladorUsuarios::ctrEditarUsuario() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\cautiva_hse\vistas\plantilla.php(107): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #3

Comment: entonces no es esa la linea 150, lo que estamos haciendo o intentando es depurar donde o que produce el error "Path cannot be empty" es como si estubieras buscando una imagen que no existe... intenta con: var_dump($_FILES["editarFoto"]["tmp_name"]);  exit();

Comment: de tal manera que se salga de la ejecucion antes de llegar al Fatal error

Comment: esto lo pongo en esa misma línea?

Comment: en teoria si lo pones en una sola linea deberia de funcionar igual  con tal que lo pongas antes del if

Comment: ahora no sale el error...pero no se modifica el usuario y sale esto....string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php682F.tmp"

Comment: ¿El nombre del archivo tiene espacio(s)?. También revisa el valor de `$_FILES['editarFoto']['error']`.

Comment: Tal y como te dice @Sal, lo más probable es que el contenido de `$_FILES["editarFoto"]["tmp_name"]` esté vacío porque se ha producido un error en el envío y, por lo tanto, la variable existe pero está vacía. El motivo está en el índice `error`, y en la documentación puedes ver el significado de cada código de error: [https://php.net/features.file-upload.errors](https://php.net/features.file-upload.errors).

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esta linea, y el error es porque no se guarda la foto.

```
$foto=addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']));
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe qué hace este código. Lee [answer].

Answer (score -2):

Deberías de utilizar la función move_upload_file, válida si se sube correctamente el fichero. Te dejo un ejemplo de uso de la documentación de PHP

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        // basename() may prevent filesystem traversal attacks;
        // further validation/sanitation of the filename may be appropriate
        $name = basename($_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key]);
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
?>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php#refsect1-function.move-uploaded-file-examples

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/375988)

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo @mateo , en este caso era un enlace a la documentación oficial que no ha cambiado en +10 años. Pero es verdad que puede cambiar en cualquier momento ☺️, subsanado

Comment: @Mateo mejor de esta forma?